# Problem with webscraping, not working to click on element

Tags: python

I have tried to loop through this website and press on each element/button but I always get nontype error... https://www.coop.se/globalt-sok/?query=coop&category=stores&page=1
[image]
and here is the website I tried to click on each element/green button
[image]

My code is here:

```
buttons = soup.find_all('div', class_='Grid-cell js-storeResult u- 
cursorPointer')


if len(buttons) == 0:
    print("----------------------------------------")
    print("----------------------------------------")
    print("Jumped over this page",driver.current_url)
    print("----------------------------------------")
    print("----------------------------------------")
    continue
else:


 for button in buttons:
        Store = button.find("div").attrs["data-name"]

        test = button.find('div', {'class':'Button Button-- 
               greenButton--small Button--radius'})
        test.click()
```

Comment: Please post code and errors as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that `test` is `None`, probably because the button was not found.

When you open the website in Firefox, right-click on the green button and choose *Inspect Element(Q)*, you'll see that the class is actually **Button Button--green Button--radius**.

Comment: Tried it out but gave me same error again.

Answer (score 0):

it's useful to use try, except to catch any exceptions when using find or click. joao commented already an incorrect class name will also mean a button can't be found:

```
for button in buttons:
    Store = button.find("div").attrs["data-name"]
    try:
        test = button.find('div', {'class':'Button Button--green Button--radius'})
        test.click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I got the error
"'NoneType' object is not callable"

Comment: Sorry, I see now you are using BeautifulSoup it is only an HTML parser. If you want to find and click buttons in a browser then use the selenium  library https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/web_element/

Answer (score 0):

Just checked all of the methods what bs4.element.Tag has and there's no click() method:

> ['**bool**', '**call**', '**class**', '**contains**', '**copy**',
> '**delattr**', '**delitem**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**',
> '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattr**', '**getattribute**',
> '**getitem**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**init_subclass**',
> '**iter**', '**le**', '**len**', '**lt**', '**module**', '**ne**',
> '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**',
> '**setitem**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**',
> '**unicode**', '**weakref**', '_all_strings', '_find_all',
> '_find_one', '_is_xml', '_lastRecursiveChild', '_last_descendant',
> '_should_pretty_print', 'append', 'attrs', 'can_be_empty_element',
> 'cdata_list_attributes', 'childGenerator', 'children', 'clear',
> 'contents', 'decode', 'decode_contents', 'decompose', 'decomposed',
> 'descendants', 'encode', 'encode_contents', 'extend', 'extract',
> 'fetchNextSiblings', 'fetchParents', 'fetchPrevious',
> 'fetchPreviousSiblings', 'find', 'findAll', 'findAllNext',
> 'findAllPrevious', 'findChild', 'findChildren', 'findNext',
> 'findNextSibling', 'findNextSiblings', 'findParent', 'findParents',
> 'findPrevious', 'findPreviousSibling', 'findPreviousSiblings',
> 'find_all', 'find_all_next', 'find_all_previous', 'find_next',
> 'find_next_sibling', 'find_next_siblings', 'find_parent',
> 'find_parents', 'find_previous', 'find_previous_sibling',
> 'find_previous_siblings', 'format_string', 'formatter_for_name',
> 'get', 'getText', 'get_attribute_list', 'get_text', 'has_attr',
> 'has_key', 'hidden', 'index', 'insert', 'insert_after',
> 'insert_before', 'isSelfClosing', 'is_empty_element', 'known_xml',
> 'name', 'namespace', 'next', 'nextGenerator', 'nextSibling',
> 'nextSiblingGenerator', 'next_element', 'next_elements',
> 'next_sibling', 'next_siblings', 'parent', 'parentGenerator',
> 'parents', 'parserClass', 'parser_class', 'prefix',
> 'preserve_whitespace_tags', 'prettify', 'previous',
> 'previousGenerator', 'previousSibling', 'previousSiblingGenerator',
> 'previous_element', 'previous_elements', 'previous_sibling',
> 'previous_siblings', 'recursiveChildGenerator', 'renderContents',
> 'replaceWith', 'replaceWithChildren', 'replace_with',
> 'replace_with_children', 'select', 'select_one', 'setup', 'smooth',
> 'string', 'strings', 'stripped_strings', 'text', 'unwrap', 'wrap']

that's why error appears:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Moreover, **BeautifulSoup** is an HTML parser, it can't manipulate a webpage, you should use smth like selenium

Answer (score 0):

You need to try to find the button by a different method. Instead of a div look with a specific attribute name, try a combination of different priorities. Plus you should prefer doing web scraping using selenium since that gives you multiple options to locate elements smoothly. Try to search using class name or a part of it